# Accessing Facebook through code

Tags: java, facebook

I want to write an application in java to log in to my facebook account and then search for individual people and when I have a profile link of a person. I want to download that webpage and parse it.

I have already written a code to login to FB using an Http library to POST messages.  Now I want to open an individual's profile page and download it and parse it.  For that I have to maintain my login session information to be able to access the profile of a person.

The public profile of a person on FB is totally different than it looks to any one having a FB account (even if he is not friends with that person on FB) and I want to see that person's profile with my login informaton.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/).

Comment: Yes as one of the friend here mentioned , I am using restfb , which is implementation of FB's graph API in java ... but I am not writing any FB applicaion.. I am trying to build a search engine sort of applicaiton to search individual on FB and get public information available for that particular person.

Answer (score 2):

There are two java libraries for the facebook APIs (it has Graph API and old rest API):

- [restfb](http://restfb.com/)
- [facebook-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/)

I'm using restfb and it's fine.

Comment: I am infact using that restfb API, but with that API I can only access limited information of individual ( who is not my friend )  . .which only includes name, firstname, lastname, gender (only if its visible), profile pic and public link of a profile . . I want to access more details .. which is not possible through the api I suppose even if I have access token.

Comment: but I am not writing any FB applicaion.. I am trying to build a search engine sort of applicaiton to search individual on FB and get public information available for that particular person.

Comment: it doesn't matter you are not building an app that runs inside facebook - the only entry point is the API. And yes - the information is limited, but that's everything you can get

Comment: so is there any way with which I can download the webpage of a person and parse the page to get additional information .

Comment: that's called scraping, and no, you can't. First, because most profiles are not public, and 2nd, because facebook will ban you if you do it

Comment: yah, that is what I was thinking. I have created an account on facebook and I am using that account's credentials ( username and password ) to login to my account and then I am extracting my access token ( which gets generated every time a user login to facebook) and I am using that access token to create queries for search through facebook's graph API but as I mentioned before I am only able to get 5 attiributes and not much information other than that .. So as I said I am using a sort of dummy account for all this, so is this a breach of FB's policy??